# Safari crashes on zoom viewport settings above 1.3

Tags: ipad, mobile, safari, zooming

For some reason, an application we're working on at [dynalog-qa.catalogs.com](http://dynalog-qa.catalogs.com) seems to consistently crash as soon as the zoom level is above 1.3.  This only happens on iOS and isn't occuring on my iOS simulator. It's extremely hard to debug, of course, because the logs provide mostly machine code and a bunch of stuff that I'm unable to understand.

So far, we've tried quite a few things:

1. Removing *any* calls to webkit animations / transitions
2. Removing a large (and often troublesome and buggy) JS plugin [turn.js](http://www.turnjs.com) from the repository
3. Changing the meta viewport user-scalable setting (we tried various increments and found that at 1.3, the crashing stopped)

Unfortunately, this entire site is a Backbone application, so many articles suggestion to remove Javascript won't help much (because we can't really test without Javascript).

I know this is an insanely hard issue to debug and test, much less explain––but that being said, anyone's help or advice would be as always greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same problem. Have you figured anything out since you posted this? I'm able to reproduce this on an iPad 1 running iOS 5.1.1, but not on an iPad 2 running iOS 7.0.3. The funny thing is that we're a Backbone (Marionette) app too...